# SQL Server 2008 Create table error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, create-table

I was trying to execute this query below but, the SQL Server returns this error:

> Incorrect syntax definition of constraint ' TABLE'

Here the part of the query which have the error

```
create table Vendedor
(
    Vend_idVendedor int identity,
    Vend_Nome VARCHAR(45) not null,
    Vend_CPF int not null,
    Vend_Cargo VARCHAR(15) not null,
    Vend_Salario FLOAT not null,
    Vend_Telefone INT not null,
    Vend_Celular INT not null,
    Vend_Admissao DATE not null,

    constraint PK_Vend_idVend primary key (Vend_idVendedor),

    constraint CK_Vend_CPF check(len(Vend_CPF) = 11),
    constraint CK_Vend_Tel check(len(Vend_Telefone) = 10),
    constraint CK_Vend_Cel check(len(Vend_Celular) = 11),

    constraint UQ_Vend_CPF unique(Vend_CPF),
    constraint UQ_Vend_Cel unique(Vend_Celular),

    constraint CK_Vend_Adm check(Vend_Admissao >= '2016-01-02' and Vend_Admissao <= getdate())
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the above statement. It created a table on my SQL 2008 R2 Dev.

Check for errors in the preceding statements.

If you working in SSMS you can try adding right before and after your statement a batch separator (`GO`) to isolate it. Semi-colon (;) may help as well.

Comment: Thank You Alex, now i'm getting "there is already an object named 'int' in the database"

Comment: As I said the error is not in the code you have posted. I cannot possibly guess where and what the error is if I can't see the code. The only thing that the error tells me is that you are trying to create an object (SP, function or table) with the name "int" and it already exists in the database. You need to either post a complete code sample (if it is not too big) or find the error yourself. If you are using SSMS you should see the line number next to the error message (it does not always show the correct line), if you double-click on the error message it will take you to the line.

Comment: Also you can try Googling the error messages to find their meaning.

Comment: Edit: an object in SQL Server can refer to many different things, not just an SP, function or table

Comment: Thank You, I was read my guide, and found the error, Thank You for the help ;)

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if my answer and comments have helped you.